# Find matrix of endomorphism $\phi+\psi$ in the basis $(b_1,b_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Given $\phi$ endomorphism in the basis $a_1=(1,2)$, $a_2=(2,3)$ with matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\5&3\\ \end{bmatrix}$

and $\psi$ endomorphism with basis $b_1=(3,1),b_2=(4,2)$ and matrix $\begin{bmatrix}4&6\\6&9\\ \end{bmatrix}$

Find matrix of endomorphism $\phi+\psi$ in the basis $(b_1,b_2)$

So matrix of endomorphism if I correctly remember is this
$\phi(1)=3\times2+4\times3 = 18$,
$\phi(2)=5\times2+3\times3=19$

$\psi(1)=6\times4+9\times2=42$,
$\psi(3)=4\times4+6\times2=28$

To find matrix of $\psi+\phi$ in that basis we need to express $(\psi+\phi)(3) ,(\psi+\phi)(1)$ in terms of $b_2$

$\phi(3)+\psi(3) = 65$
$\phi(1)+\psi(1)=60$

So matrix I get is

$\begin{bmatrix}16&15\\\frac{1}{2}&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$
Can you tell what I did is right? Maybe this is wrong way to do?

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi(1)$ ? $\phi$ is an endomorphism of a 2 dimensionnal vector space so it should take a 2D vectors as inputs and return a 2D vector as an output ! I don't even understand where all these calculations come from ? Or how you're using the numbers you find as a result. $18,19,42,28,65$ and $60$ are never used in an obvious way later on. Maybe you should clarify what you mean by $\phi(1)$ and $\psi(3)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

A $2\times 2$ matrix send vectors of $\mathbb R^{2}$ to vectors of $\mathbb R^{2}$, that is one cannot write $\phi(1)$, but rather $\phi((1,0))$, or in general $\phi((a,b))$.

If $A$ is a matrix representing a linear map $\phi$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{A}$ is the domain and in the codomain, and you want to find the matrix $B$ representing $\phi$ with respect to another basis $\mathcal{B}$, it suffices to compute the matrix $M$ that send the basis $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$, hence $B=MAM^{-1}$.

To find the matrix $M$, it suffices to compute the vectors of $\mathcal{A}$ as linear combination of vectors of $\mathcal{B}$, that is solve the linear system
$$\begin{bmatrix}b_{1} & b_{2}\end{bmatrix}M=\begin{bmatrix}a_{1} & a_{2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

In your case you have to solve
$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2 & 3\end{bmatrix},$$
which is left to you.

Hence, $\phi+\psi$ is represented in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ by $$M\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\ 5 & 3\end{bmatrix}M^{-1}+\begin{bmatrix}4 & 6\\6& 9\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Why you added matrix of $\psi$ in your last equation?

Comment: Because you asked for $\phi+\psi$ with respect to the basis $\{b_1,b_2\}$. $\psi$ is by hypothesis written in the correct basis, hence you only need to add it.

Comment: Thank you and please can you explain how you got $B=MAM^{-1}$ @ecrin

Comment: $M$ is the matrix that "converts" a vector written in the basis $\mathcal A$ in a vector written in the basis $\mathcal B$, conversely $M^{-1}$ "converts" a vector written in the basis $\mathcal B$ in a vector written in the basis $\mathcal A$. To understand how $\phi$ acts on a vector $v$ written in the basis $\mathcal B$ you first "translate" it in the basis $\mathcal A$, that is $M^{-1}v$, then you apply $A$. that is $AM^{-1}v$ and finally you translate it back in the basis $\mathcal B$, that is $MAM^{-1}v$, that is $\phi(v)=MAM^{-1}v$ and $\phi=MAM^{-1}$.

Comment: However, this is a really basic topic in linear algebra, I suggest you to read it in a book, it will be more useful than my explanation.